# String sent over socket in Python will not compare to equivalent string once .recv'd

Tags: python, sockets

Ignoring the larger scope of my code, there is one particular part that is not working properly.

I send to a server a GET request for a file from a client over TCP. I am opening the file (.html in this particular case) on the server side, reading through it and sending the file over to the client. The client is supposed to receive until the file transfer is complete, and then continue to the next step which is parsing the HTML file and sending subsequent requests.

The part that is not working is the reception of the end message. I have tried sending an explicit "END" message upon completion of sending the HTML file, and I have tried sending an empty string. What is problematic is that when the client receives the end message, whether it be a string like "END" or empty, it does not compare correctly. Doing .strip() to the termination message on the client side when comparing it in the if statement does not help. See the following snippet of code.

server.py

```
##socket setup and file open/read
while True:
    conn.send(buffer)
    buffer = htmlFile.read(1460)
    if buffer == "":
        conn.send("END")
        break
```

client.py

```
##socket setup and GET request send
while True:
    chunk = clientSocket.recv(1500)
    if chunk == "END":
        break
    else:
        total = total + chunk
print "received all chunks"
```

I would expect once the file transfer to be done on the server side for it to send "END". It does so. When I have client print out every chunk it receives, it will print out the entire HTML file perfectly, and then add "END" to it, and then go back to the .recv() line listed above.

Why does it not break out of this receive loop once the "END" message if received?

I can include more code if needed but I am very confident that the rest is working right, considering client.py prints the HTML code properly, and is obviously receiving the "END" message. It just isn't getting caught by the if for some reason....

v2.7.10, running on latest Ubuntu in a virtual machine, if it matters.

Comment: Is this Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: 2.7.10, running on latest Ubuntu. I'll add to question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP doesn't preserve the borders of your messages sent over socket. Messages can stick to each other or fall apart into several messages. `N` `send` commands doesn't mean you need `N` `recv`. It is up to your *application protocol level* to separate received data into messages.

In your case, you get `END` message alongside with the last part of the file.
In order to overcome this, you can start with this: `if chunk.endswith("END"):` (if you don't send anything after the file, so `END` will be indeed in the end)
and [this link about TCP message framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).

Comment: This is the answer. I was not aware about the borders, so that is fantastic. Thank you! And if I wanted to add that final chunk minus the end message, would I just do "total = total + chunk[:-3]" before my BREAK?

Comment: This is correct. I have stumbled upon something similar myself and solved it by adding \0 at the end of each packet. In my case, it was important to be able to tell exactly where are borders of my messages. In the client script I could then detect \0 and split messages appropriately. In your case, chunk.endswith("END") should do the trick.

Comment: Can you guarantee that a particular chunk won't end with `END` though, if that sequence of characters are present somewhere in the middle of the file?

Comment: @nekomatic yes, this is the issue. One can find the solution in sending *n* bytes of message length prior to sending message itself (where n is known to client and server) rather than introducing delimiters.

Comment: Yes I am positive, the HTML file is clearly defined. At any rate, I put "END" in the example above for simplicity. In reality, I'm using "|||END" to denote the end of a file transfer, which should never appear (if I'm lucky :D)

Comment: @Mirza once you make sure you've got the whole file and `total` doesn't have any part of the next possible message (or even two whole messages!), doing something like `total = total + chunk[:-3]` is ok.

Comment: Even `chunk.endswith("END")` is not guaranteed to work -- the 'END' string could be split across two chunks. Better would be to check `total.endswith("END")` after the `total = total + chunk`.